# How to check if website is up and store results for long time period

Tags: php, mysql, database, monitoring, large-data

I'm monitoring a website (using curl) to see if it's up and to know the response time for a simple GET request on the homepage. I'm using a homemade script to do this, and I don't want to use Nagios or any other existing tool for that.

My problem is that I have no idea how to store the results for a long time period (say, months). I don't need the response time for every single request since epoch of course, but i'd like to get the status (up|down) and an average response time for large periods. 
For example :

1. [ last month] -> daily response time (avg)
2. [ last 3 months ] -> weekly response time (avg)
3. [ last 12 months ] -> monthly response time (avg)

And for the whole duration, I want to keep the status. For that I will just save the last date when a status change happened I guess.

So the question is : what is the optimal way to store that kind of information with this frequency/retention ? I'm coding in PHP with a Mysql DB behind, but maybe there's something better than a DB for that ?

Any language/tech is accepted as long as it's free and running on linux/unix.

Thank you

Comment: You already have the best tools available. You solution is the optimal one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a typical round-robin database. [RRDtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/) allows you to manage such a database. I don't see a reason for re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Save every request to DB table and to calcualte `daily response time (avg)`, `weekly response time (avg)` and `monthly response time (avg)` write simple PHP functions.

If you gona store only response times and request dates your table wouldn't grow fast and with correct indexes will work fast.